# Keras LSTM for time-series bad prediction and convergance to unchangable range of values

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, keras, forecasting, lstm

the model:

```
def buildModel(neurons= 5, batch_size= 1, timestep=1, features=1):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(neurons, 
                   batch_input_shape=(batch_size, timestep, features), 
                   #return_sequences= True,
                   stateful=True))

    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',  
                  metrics=[metrics.MAPE, 'accuracy'])
    return model
```

Test RMSE: 0.104
Test MAPE: 14.040

but when running multi-step forecasting step by step the results increase rapidly and then stablize at a certain range.

the time-series is univariate
any suggestions related to the model or to the time-series prediction problem ?

Answer (score 1):

`neurons = 5`, this is a very low capacity model. Might not be enough to model the targeted time series function.

`timesteps = 1`, this is time series so the output must be dependent on a certain number of `timesteps` before a correct prediction should be made. `timesteps = 1` means your output is only dependent on 1 `timestep`.

`batch_size = 1`, this will take a while to converge. Normally, this should be power of 2 (16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512).

Comment: thanks rowel for your tips. i'm just new to the field and needed some help